# invalid salt (BCrypt::Errors::InvalidSalt)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt, sorcery

Since upgraded to Ruby 2.2.0 I get the following message in my tests:

```
invalid salt (BCrypt::Errors::InvalidSalt)
```

I didn't find any upgrade notice helping me to understand the problem. I'm using Rails 4.1.8 and Sorcery 0.8.6.

Anybody else having this problem?

MORE Details:

I'm using Sorcery and not Devise. The encrypted data is the password.
It all started in Cucumber tests, in 2 cases:
When I used to send the @user to the mailer to prepare the data for the mails. Here was the code:

UserMailer.passphrase_reset_notification(@user).deliver

Which generated the exception with the message I wrote in the initial message. As a workaround instead of sending the @user I sent the fields I needed and it worked. Here's the new code:

UserMailer.passphrase_reset_notification(@user.name, @user.email).deliver

But the second case is the sign up. It failed in dev and I had to add :salt to user_params to fix it. But it does not fix the thing in the test env.

There's no stack trace, just that one liner message with the lines of my scenario leading to the error.

And I press "Sign up"
      invalid salt (BCrypt::Errors::InvalidSalt)
      ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:66:in `block in create'
      ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:64:in`create'
      ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:120:in `scope_current_tenant'
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:53:in`/^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/users/sign_up.feature:149:in `And I press "Sign up"'

I removed the "null: false" for the field "salt" in the user table, as suggested by a community member in a post on a more or less similar issue, it didn't help either.

My main question is still the same: what the Ruby new version (2.2.0) has to do with this? And what might be the other surprises if I upgrade the prod?

Comment: are you using the devise gem or what is it that you are trying to encrypt?

Comment: The stack-trace would help narrow this down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** FIXED **
The problem, at least mine, is fixed. I just upgraded the bcrypt gem from 3.1.
9 to 3.1.10 and it was it! Thanks Oleg to have created an issue on bcrypt account.

Comment: upgrading the gem immediately worked for me too.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed this. Turned out it had to do with serializing an object with `has_secure_password` (which uses `bcrypt-ruby`)

More specifically, something like the following was causing the issue with Sidekiq as it tried to serialize arguments into objects for Redis queueing.

```
@user = User.new(
  :firstname => 'Scott',
  :lastname => 'Klein',
  :password => 'mypass',
  :password_confirmation => 'mypass'   
)
@user.save!

# broken
# note that @user.password can still be called here
# and sidekiq will attempt to serialize this whole object using YAML
# and this is the serialization issue that barfs (in the depths of YAML)
UserMailer.delay.new_user_signup(@user)

# fixed
# i just passed the id and then recalled the user record in the mailer class
UserMailer.delay.new_user_signup(@user.id)
```

Comment: Does not help. Thanks.
The exception happens on "save" call. When I trace into the code it immediately raises the exception!

Comment: Im using DelayedJob...but this was my fix too.  Remove the object (@user), just pass the id instead, then get the object later inside the mailer method.

Comment: Pretty nasty bug... Your fix saved my day !

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problem. Investigation made me conclude that it's bcrypt not playing well with Psych (that's the Ruby system library for generating and parsing YAML).

There's an open bcrypt [issue](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/106) now. Waiting for gem author to fix it.

Comment: Well spotted Oleg. Let's wait for a fix from BCrypt team.